# Where to store progress information in ASP.Net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm creating a page that get uploaded text files and builds them into multiple PDFs. They are just exports from Excel. Each row in the file corresponds to a new PDF that needs to be created.

Anyway, once the files are uploaded I want to begin processing them, but I don't want the user to have to stay on the page, or even still have their session open. For example they could close the browser and come back 10 minutes later, log in, and the progress information will say like 112/200 files processed or something. It will be a lot quicker than that though.

So two questions really, how can I pass this processing job to something (Handler?Thread?) that will continue to run when the page is closed, and will return as soon as the job has started (so the browser isn't stopped)? Secondly, where can I store this information so that when the user comes back to the page, they can see the current progress.

I realise that I can't use sessions, and since it will be processing about a file a second I don't *really* want to update a DB every second. Is there some way I can do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Have a look at something like http://blog.bluesam.com/2008/06/running-batch-jobs-in-aspnet-web.html This might get you going in the right direction.

Comment: That looks like the sort of thing I'm looking for, I'll have a look when I get home

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by using the link provided by astander above. I simply create an object in the HttpContext.Application to store progress variables, and then Set the method which does my processing inside a new Thread.

```
// Create the new progress object
BatchProgress bs = new BatchProgress(0);
if(Application["BatchProgress"] != null)
{
    // Should never happen
    Application["BatchProgress"] = bs;
}
else
{
    Application.Add("BatchProgress","bs");
}

//Set up new thread, run batch is the method that does all the processing.
ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(RunBatch);
Thread t = new Thread(ts);
t.Start();
```

It then returns after the thread starts and I can use jQuery to get the Application["BatchProgress"] object at regular intervals. At the end of my thread the BatchProgress object has its status set to "Complete", then when jQuery queries it, it sees the complete status and removes the progress object from the application.

Comment: This may seem to work in testing, but you have two big problems here.  The first is that if no one visits your site for a while, your processing batch might get killed off.  The second is that the HttpContext.Application() item is _shared_ by all users of your site, so one user could end up over-writing another user's batch reference and see their progress information.  Instead, you need to build a windows service and talk to that.

Comment: Oh I did not know the batch would be killed off, that's a bit of a concern. The batch reference will not allow overwriting however, the functionality required to use the page is only available if the Application["BatchProgress"] is equal to null, otherwise the server controls are removed from the page and instead the BatchProgress is displayed. It will only be 1 user using this on an administration site, so I only need 1 batch at a time. The batch will be run weekly. How long before my processing batch will be killed off?

Comment: It depends on a setting in IIS, and how much traffic your site gets.  I think the default is something like 20 minutes of idle time, but my memory is fuzzy on the exact time limit. After that, the app pool hosting the site is shut down.  So if you have even a popular site on the public internet, you're fine. If this is in it's own app pool and only one person ever visits it once a week, you could have problems.

Comment: Well I don't expect this to take more than 20 minutes hopefully, but It is likely that noone will visit the site for hours, it does have other functionality for other administrators but its obviously not used all the time. Thanks for the information I'll have a look at windows services instead.